# How to upgrade Magento 2 cloud version from 2.4.5-p1 to 2.4.5-p2 ? without upgrade third party extensions

Tags: magento2, magento-upgrade, magento2.4.5p1, version-upgrade

I have tried to upgrade using "composer require-commerce magento/magento-cloud-metapackage:'2.4.5-p2 < 2.4.6' --no-update" this composer command but it's returning the error like

[image]

Please help me out if anyone have done this before.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's just that it goes to search the wrong version name. What if you edit directly your composer.json `magento/magento-cloud-metapackage : 2.4.5-p2` and replace it by `magento/magento-cloud-metapackage : 2.4.6`

Then run `COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer update`

Answer (score 0):

please run commands like :-

**`composer require-commerce magento/magento-cloud-metapackage:">=2.4.5 <2.4.6" --no-update`**